# Not able to link the template page of Django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to make an application using `django-allauth`; My `Django` version is `1.11.5`.

I am trying to display the result on another template: `facebook_personality_traits.html`

Here is the code:

**settings.py**

```
SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'facebook_personality_traits/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'user_posts'],
        # 'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
                    ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True
    }
}
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
```

**views.py**

```
def fb_personality_traits(request):
    # logger.debug('FB Page Loaded')
    return render(request, 'home/facebook_personality_traits.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
   url(r'^facebook_personality-traits/$', views.fb_personality_traits, name="fb_personality_traits"),
```

**facebook_personality_traits.html**

```
<html>


<body>

 Welcome back {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name}}


<a href="/">Home</a>
</body>


</html>
```

But I could able to make it run effectively. I guess there is some issue where I have declared the url for the site. Here is the snapshot of the error:

[image: issue snapshot.]

Kindly suggest me the missed part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using different urls.py for your apps. However you placed your url in to main urls.py.

```
url(r'^facebook_personality-traits/&', views.fb_personality_traits, name="fb_personality_traits"),
```

put this line to your apps urls.py where you put `facebook_callback` url like this:

```
url(r'^login/token/facebook_personality_traits/$', views.fb_personality_traits, name="fb_personality_traits"),
```

BTW you have excessive & char at the end of your url, I guess you would like to put $ sign which represents end of line in regex.

**EDIT 1:**

My first impression about the problem was you were not putting the url in the right place but as far as i see, the redirection is done from a page under this path `/accounts/facebook/login/token/`. Since there is no preceding `/` at your redirect url in `settings.py` it causes relative redirection.

Fix your url as following:

```
url(r'^facebook_personality_traits/$', views.fb_personality_traits, name="fb_personality_traits"),
```

In your settins.py you have set redirect url like below:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'facebook_personality_traits/'
```

Since this is relative url, it goes to the url `/accounts/facebook/login/token/facebook_personality_traits/`. Put a slash `/` at the beginning of `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` than your problem will be solved.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/facebook_personality_traits/'
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156342/discussion-between-scriptmonster-and-jaffer-wilson).

Answer (score 2):

your urls:

```
facebook_personality-traits/
```

but you test other url

```
facebook_personality_traits/
#                ^^^^^^
```

need to change somewhere